# How to make a div with arrowlike side without css border tricks?

Tags: html, css

I want to make menu navigation bar with several inline-block li elements, each of them must have arrow-like right side. Like this:
[image: my dream menu aww]

I googled for it and the most common answer is to use css tricks with transparent border. Like this one: http://jsfiddle.net/jx99z/5/

html:

```
<div class="text">Some Text<span class="arrow"></span></div>
```

css:

```
.text {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:4px;
}
.arrow {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0.20em;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
    /* Use font-size to control the size of the arrow. */
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    background-color:#fff; /* change background color acc to bg color */ 
    border-left-width: 0.2em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
    left:0.25em;
}
```

It seems pretty good, but when I try to add other elements with :hover, they don't look and behave properly: http://jsfiddle.net/txayr2j6/

html:

```
<div class="text">Some Text<span class="arrow"></span></div>
<div class="text">Some Text<span class="arrow"></span></div>
```

css:

```
.text {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:4px;
}
.arrow {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0.20em;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
    /* Use font-size to control the size of the arrow. */
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    background-color:#fff; /* change background color acc to bg color */ 
    border-left-width: 0.2em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
    left:0.25em;
}
.text:hover {
    background-color:#ccc;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
}
```

Another solution, which I found, is that I can draw any element using svg (whatever that means) like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXWoXd

html:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <polygon points="
    0,0 
    0,200
    270,200
    300,100
    270,0
    150,0
    " />
<div>Item 1</div>
</svg>
```

css:

```
svg polygon {
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

svg {
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 50%; 
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: .2em; 
}
```

But that solution is even worse: somehow I can't make element wider than 300 px and look at those ugly border and background. Also, I want that bar to be responsive. Thanks!

Comment: Using images may be better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Svg are great for creating shapes in html

Used a **polygon element** for the shape.
**Text element** for the link description.
**A element** for creating a link.

```css
#arrow-menu a polygon {
  fill: #888;
  stroke: #222;
}
#arrow-menu a:hover polygon {
  stroke: #222;
  fill: black;
}
#arrow-menu a:hover text {
  fill: cornflowerblue;
}
#arrow-menu a {
  font-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="arrow-menu" viewBox="-1 -1 112 22" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 0,0"></polygon>
    <text x="1.5" y="11.5">Menu link</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon transform="translate(22)" points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 5,10 0,0"></polygon>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon transform="translate(44)" points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 5,10 0,0"></polygon>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <polygon transform="translate(66)" points="0,0 20,0 25,10 20,20 0,20 5,10 0,0"></polygon>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Whoa.. That's awesome! I knew, that there should be proper way to do that. You probably will hate me, but may be you can prompt me how to put that consctruction in wordpress menu? Serious question

Comment: I did some searching for this, and it seems like there is no plugin for wordpress where you can add a custom svg menu. So your only option is to edit in this menu in the file `home.php` and if you you not 110% on php code then i would not recommend it.

Comment: @ArturMiller May I suggest you consider chose this brilliant solution as the accepted one?

Comment: @LGSon, probably, you are right, I should do that. Though I am really appretiate first solution and I successfully used it on my site

Comment: @ArturMiller SO is not about the best solution for the problem not the first solution that worked

Answer (score 3):

Is it this what you are looking for? It is made with `before` and `after` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv3xkg0g/9/)

It is better to make it with css than with images

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Need some changes to be responsive, but it's working just perfect! Appreciate thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question. I believe it is better to use pictures, since you want your hover event to work and also, there is a problem with clicking at the borders. This is a full implementation of the design along with events:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .text {
                background-color: rgb(237, 28, 36);
                color:white;
                padding-left:4px;
                height: 30px;
                padding-top: 10px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mouseoverText(index) {
                var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
                var currentText = document.querySelectorAll(".text")[index];
                currentText.style["background-color"] = "white";
                currentText.style["color"] = "red";
                images[index].src = ((images.length - 1 === index) ? "white-white" : "white-red") + "-arrow.png";
                if (index > 0) {
                    images[index - 1].src = "red-white-arrow.png";
                }
            }

            function mouseoutText(index) {
                var currentText = document.querySelectorAll(".text")[index];
                currentText.style["background-color"] = "rgb(237, 28, 36)";
                currentText.style["color"] = "white";
                var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image");
                if (index >= 0) {
                    images[index].src = ((images.length - 1 === index) ? "red-white" : "red-red") + "-arrow.png";
                    if (index > 0) {
                        images[index - 1].src = "red-red-arrow.png";
                    }
                }
            }

            var lastIndex = -1;

            function mouseoverArrow(event, index) {
                if (!!event) {
                    var x = event.offsetX;
                    var y = event.offsetY;
                    var height = 40;
                    if (((y < height / 2) && (x > y)) || ((y >= height / 2) && (x > (height - y)))) {
                        mouseoverArrow(null, index + 1);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (lastIndex !== -1) {
                    mouseoutArrow();
                    lastIndex = -1;
                }
                lastIndex = index;
                var texts = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
                if (index === texts.length) {
                    return;
                }
                texts[index].style["background-color"] = "white";
                texts[index].style.color = "red";
                mouseoverText(index);
            }

            function mouseoutArrow() {
                if (lastIndex < 0) {
                    return;
                }
                var texts = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
                if (lastIndex >= texts.length) {
                    return;
                }
                texts[lastIndex].style.color = "white";
                texts[lastIndex].style["background-color"] = "rgb(237, 28, 36)";
                mouseoutText(lastIndex);
                lastIndex = -1;
            }

            function clk(index) {
                console.log("Element " + (lastIndex === -1 ? index : lastIndex) + " was clicked");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="display: inline-flex;">
            <div class="text" onmousemove="mouseoverText(0);" onmouseout="mouseoutText(0);" onclick="clk(0);">Some Text</div>
            <img class="image" src="red-red-arrow.png" onmousemove="mouseoverArrow(event, 0);" onmouseout="mouseoutArrow();" onclick="clk();" />
            <div class="text" onmousemove="mouseoverText(1);" onmouseout="mouseoutText(1);" onclick="clk(1);">Some Text</div>
            <img class="image" src="red-red-arrow.png" onmousemove="mouseoverArrow(event, 1);" onmouseout="mouseoutArrow();" onclick="clk();" />
            <div class="text" onmousemove="mouseoverText(2);" onmouseout="mouseoutText(2);" onclick="clk(2);">Some Text</div>
            <img class="image" src="red-white-arrow.png" onmousemove="mouseoverArrow(event, 2);" onmouseout="mouseoutArrow();" onclick="clk();" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I attach the useful pictures as well:

[image]    [image]    [image]    [image]