# CSS - Shaping a button that way?

Tags: css

So I've seen making shapes in CSS is possible, but there's one shape what I'm not that sure about, so I'm asking here. Is shape like that possible:

[image: a busy cat]

Why is this marked as duplicate? It isn't im not trying to achive something like that. Like it's linked for the duplicate.

Comment: Have a look at this post/answer, it will show you how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38038730/2827823

Comment: Hmm, been trying for 2 hours.. Still haven't succeed. Is there someone who could help me a bit?

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to use multiple divs to achieve what you're trying to make it look like. Some of the borders will have to be hidden, and you'll need to set overflow-x and overflow-y rules to cut out pieces of each shape div that you don't need. It's possible but I don't know if it would be worth the effort. Another solution would be to make an image with that shape and for the curved portion on the right, if you want it to be directly aligned with the circular scribbly shape then you'd need to position it properly, and also make sure the image doesn't have a background, it will display as a square/rectangle no matter what you do